# how to move main menu to right corner and squares down to the text?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make Iphone 6/7/8 version for my site.
Unfortuantely I do not know how to move my main menu to right corner so it would look like this in web site: [image]

Right now the site looks like this:

[image]

Could you tell me how to move this menu?
What is more, I do not know how to move this 6 squares down to the text. I'm trying to usse marigin-bottom etc on SquaresDOWN div or UP but nothing is happening.

I'd really appreciate if you could help me with these two things.

css

```
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header
{
  width: 1920;
  height: 1080px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
  height: 1080px;
  width: auto;
  background-image:  linear-gradient(180deg, #EFEFEF00 0%, #0F4A37 100%);
}

footer{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

footer img{
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.main-nav
{
  float: right;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.main-nav li
{
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a
{
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: Bold 25px/15px Arial;
  padding: 5px;
}

#logo
{
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}

#sign a
{
  background-color: #DCDFDE;
  padding: 30px 15px 17px 15px;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}

.left h1{
  font-size: 20px;
  color:rgb(0, 1, 253);
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 500px;
}


#ourteam
{
  margin-top: 300px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:rgb(24, 188, 253);
}

#squaresUP div {

  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
#squaresDOWN div {

  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
#tytul
{
  font: Bold 20px/23px Arial;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #2699FB;
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

#tytul1
{
  font: Regular 14px/30px Arial;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #2699FB;
  margin-left: 28px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.square1 {  background: #7FC4FD 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;}
.square2 {  background: #7FC4FD 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;}
.square3 {  background: #7FC4FD 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;}
.square4 {  background: #7FC4FD 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;}
.square5 {  background: #7FC4FD 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;}
.square6 {  background: #7FC4FD 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px){

  body {
    background-image:  linear-gradient(180deg, #EFEFEF00 0%, #0F4A37 100%);
    background-size:100% 3000px;
  }
  #ourteam
  {
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-left: 700px;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 400px;
    color:rgb(24, 188, 253);
  }

  .left h1{
    font-size: 27px;
    width: 1500px;
    color:rgb(0, 1, 253);
    text-align: justify;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

  .left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 500px;
  }

  .main-nav
  {

    float: right;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 1150px;
  }

  .main-nav li
  {
    display: inline-block;

  }

  .main-nav li a
  {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: Bold 35px/15px Arial;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50px;
  }
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>DingDog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-images/style-authors.css" >
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="row">
      <ul id ="logo"> <img src="css-images/dingdog-logo.png"> </ul>

      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="">NEWS FEED</a></li>
        <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="">ABOUT DINGDOG</a></li>
        <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="authors.html">AUTHORS</a></li>
        <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li style="padding-left:10px" id ="sign"><a href="signin.html">SIGN IN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <section>
      <article>
        <p id="ourteam">Our Team.</p>
        <div class="left">
          <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam dictum nisi ac nunc lobortis auctor. Nam nec congue ex, nec ornare elit. Donec feugiat massa vitae mauris euismod malesuada. Pellentesque iaculis dui felis, sit amet molestie augue scelerisque et. Nullam eget mi neque. Ut maximus enim ac fringilla scelerisque. Quisque sit amet sem semper, rutrum nulla eu, fermentum sapien. ILorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam dictum nisi ac nunc lobortis auctor. Nam nec congue ex, nec ornare elit. Donec feugiat massa vitae mauris euismod malesuada. Pellentesque iaculis dui felis, sit amet molestie augue scelerisque et. Nullam eget mi neque. Ut maximus enim ac fringilla scelerisque. Quisque sit amet sem semper, rutrum nulla eu, fermentum sapien. ILorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam dictum nisi ac nunc lobortis auctor. Nam nec congue ex, nec ornare elit. Donec feugiat massa vitae mauris euismod malesuada. Pellentesque iaculis dui felis, sit amet molestie augue scelerisque et. Nullam eget mi neque. Ut maximus enim ac fringilla scelerisque. Quisque sit amet sem semper, rutrum nulla eu, fermentum sapien. I</h1>

        </div>
        <div class="row2">
          <div id="squaresUP">
            <div class="square1" style='position:absolute;left:1100px; top:292px;'></div>
            <div class="square2"style='position:absolute;left:1350px; top:292px;background: #F1F9FF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;'>
              <h1 id="tytul" style='position:absolute;left:0px; top:0px;'>Name Surname</h1>
              <h1 id="tytul1" style='position:absolute;left:0px; top:0px;'>Co-Founder & CTO</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="square3"style='position:absolute;left:1600px; top:292px;'></div>
          </div>
          <div id="squaresDOWN">
            <div class="square4"style='position:absolute;left:1100px; top:560px;'></div>
            <div class="square5"style='position:absolute;left:1350px; top:560px;'></div>
            <div class="square6"style='position:absolute;left:1600px; top:560px;'></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </section>
  </header>
  <footer>
    <img src="social/instagram.png" />
    <img src="social/twitter-white-logo.png" />
    <img src="social/facebook.png" />
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

//edit
the squares should be right there. They should be centered under the text.
[image]

Comment: Problem 1: Make your main-nav ```display: inline-block``` and ```white-space: nowrap```. You should look into using flexbox for this as it's best for this.

Problem 2: Can you show us where the squares are meant to be?

Comment: @BrentStees I have made an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleaned up your code a little bit and here you can find an example for how to create a header menu inside a css grid looks decent for iphone 7/8 view.
you can change the percentage based on your request to get it a bit bigger if you don't want to create more buttons,
if it doesn't helped you totally at least it could be a reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
.row{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
}
.main-nav{
    float: right;
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 50%;
}
.main-nav li{
    font-size: 50%;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">

        <div id ="logo"><img src="css-images/dingdog-logo.png"></div>
<div>
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="">NEWS FEED</a></li>
          <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="">ABOUT DINGDOG</a></li>
          <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="authors.html">AUTHORS</a></li>
          <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li style="padding-left:10px" id ="sign"><a href="signin.html">SIGN IN</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>

<!-- create your html elements and divs below -->
<!-- make sure to arrange them in a decent way to be organzied with y our page -->
<!-- i would suggest you use css grid as i did for the menu and follow almost the same settings
which will make your view look more adjusted and responsive -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: okay! got it, do you know how to move squares down to the text?

Comment: @jsonissshi sorry i wasn't aware of your question about moving the squares down, i don't know if you got it done, if not post an image or code for how you want those squares to look like

Comment: padding-left should be moved to the style tag or sheet: .main-nav li { padding-left: 10px; }